# Want to execute javascript as many times without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I want javascript to execute as many times I want to but it's only
executing once. The code below works perfectly fine but, after the
clicking of both the buttons, I have to refresh the page to make it work
again. Please help me out with this problem. Just wanna execute it as
many times I want to but without refreshing the page.

HTML:

```
<body> 
    <h1 class="head" id="h" onclick="change()">TEST PAGE</h1> 
        <form name="myform"> 
            <input name="horizontal" type="button" class="button1" value="Swap Horizontal" id="SH1" onclick="swaphorizontal()"> 
        </form> 
        <form name="myform1"> 
            <input name="vertical" type="button" class="button2" value="Swap Vertical" id="SV1" onclick="swapvertical()"> 
        </form> 
        <h2 class="mybox"></h2> 
        <h2 class="line1"></h2> 
        <h2 class="line2"></h2> 
        <h2 class="voidbutton1"></h2> 
        <h2 class="voidbutton2"></h2> 
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script>

    function swapvertical() {

        document.getElementById("SV1").style.top = "210px";

        document.getElementById("SH1").style.top = "414px";

    }
    function swaphorizontal() {

        document.getElementById("SV1").style.left = "386px";

        document.getElementById("SH1").style.left = "178px";

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Put that markup in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: What should it do? Your functions only perform one thing.

Comment: I think I will have to use a for loop but I am not really sure how to implement it. Can someone help me out.

Comment: The JavaScript will execute each time you click it.

It looks like you don't use ogposition(). swapvertical() and swaphorizontal() move your buttons to specific spots on the screen. Neither function changes something that the other function is changing, so subsequent calls to those methods obviously won't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It likely is working more than once. The problem is that all you do in your JavaScript is change values to static values.

For example, in `ogposition()`, you call `document.getElementById("SH1").style.position = "absolute";` The next time you call `ogposition()`, SH1's position is already absolute, so doing it again will not change anything, and you will not notice a difference.

If you want to know whether your code is doing something only once or more times, try putting a `console.log();` statement in the questionable section of the code.

Comment: But actually, I am only using swapvertical() and swaphorizontal().

Comment: They all do the same thing; they all change variables to constants. Unless the right side of the assignment is different each time you run it, running it more than once accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I believe the code you're looking for looks like this: `function swapVertical(){document.getElementById("SV1").style.top = document.getElementById("SH1").style.top; document.getElementById("SH1").style.top = document.getElementById("SV1").style.top; }`

Comment: Have you tried putting in a `console.log("swapVertical");` to swapVertical and seeing if it is actually being called multiple times?